# Time is displayed wrong in angular in "time" input

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So I'm trying do display the time in an Input field, but the time is displayed two hours off.

So these are the time objects:

```
start_time: date = new Date(2023, 6, 14, 7, 45);
end_time: date = new Date(2023, 6, 14, 12, 0);
```

But when I'm trying to display it, the hours are off by two:
[image]

heres the code of the input fields:

```
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Start Time</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="time" [valueAsDate]="this.start_time" #startInput>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>End Time</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="time" [valueAsDate]="this.end_time" #endInput>
    </mat-form-field>
```

I tried to provide the application with a timezone but it didn't work. I also tried to create the objects with following method:

`new Date(date.UTC(2023, 6, 14, 7, 45));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second method by creating a Date object with UTC() is working fine but you misspelled 'date'

Those two lines are working fine for your exemple

```
start_time: Date = new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 6, 14, 7, 45));
end_time: Date = new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 6, 14, 12, 0));
```

Here is a stackblitz sample where i reproduced your case
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trvy31?file=src%2Fmain.ts